# Google.GoogleApiException: The service androidpublisher has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is BadRequest. Invalid Value

Tags: c#, google-docs

```
    service.Purchases.Subscriptions.Get(packageName, subscriptionId, purchaseToken);
```

or

```
    service.Purchases.Subscriptionsv2.Get(packageName, purchaseToken);
```

generate exceptions every time, for example

The service androidpublisher has thrown an exception.

```
HttpStatusCode is BadRequest.
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Invalid Value [400]
Errors [
    Message[Invalid Value] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]
]
```

Hi, I'm new to the Google Play Store and trying to get confirmation of Subscription purchases within my Android app by querying the Google Play Android Developer API.
I know that you want to see my code (C#), but believe me, you've seen it on here before and It's not the code, it's the setup that's the problem.

So, there is so much documentation out there (that's faulty, out of date etc etc) that it's been impossible to find a good, solid, up to date, step by step plan that actually works.

In wading through all those fishy pages, this (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started#service-account)has gotten a lot of recommendations by developers on this site.

This page states, under Use A Service Account' https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started#service-account
5 To use the Google Play Billing APIs, you must grant the following permissions:

```
View financial data, orders, and cancellation survey responses
Manage orders and subscriptions
```

The issues are
a) Google Play Billing API does not exist
b If the permissions for "View financial data, orders, and cancellation survey responses" exist they are extremely difficult to find .. w
c) If the permissions for "Manage orders and subscriptions"  exist they are extremely difficult to find .. w

If you have recently, successfully implemented

```
    service.Purchases.Subscriptionsv2.Get
```

in C#, can you please post a link to a site that has a good sequence of steps to follow.

I was expecting that the Google Docs and Sample Code would provide a relatively simple and easy to implement solution. However, I was very wrong.

I have tried much, including
a) Following the Google documentation
b) Using the Google supplied dotnet examples
c) Following many, varied Google docs
d) Following steps provided in many posts on this site and others
e) Code provided in many posts on this site and some others
f) Adding many, many roles and permissions in Google Cloud
g) The API Explorer located [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptionsv2/get?) gave exactly the same errors as the code. Convincing me that most likely many of the code variants that I've tried would work fine, if only I could find some up to date, accurate documentation.
h) Asking other Dev's for help implementing a fraud check. Yep it's last on my list.